# Positional Arguments When Using Event Button

Tags: python, wxpython

I have been trying to create a GUI in wxpython that displays two plots on separate subpanels at the top, and a single panel at the. bottom with event buttons. The plots should be filled with a single slice of a 3D array when the test putton is pressed, and then the up and down buttons can be used to move through the slices of the 3D array

When pressing the test button it provides a positional argument regarding 'img'.

I have provided 'img' in the event function from pressing the button, so can see why it isnt carried through

```
import wx
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

img_start = np.ones((128,128))
data = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 255, size =(128, 128, 100))

###############################################################################
class SubPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("red")

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.axes.set_xlabel("X")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("Y")
        self.draw()

    def draw(self): 
        self.axes.imshow(img_start)

    def changeImage(self, img):
        self.axes.imshow(img)
        self.canvas.draw()

###############################################################################
class TopPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, number, color, sub_panels):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)

        label = "Panel-%s" % number
        lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label=label)

        v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        v_sizer.Add(SubPanel(self), 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND|wx.CENTER, 10)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(v_sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

###############################################################################
class button_panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.image = SubPanel
        self.slice_num = 1

        ''' Test Button '''
        self.test_btn = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Test', pos=(10,10))
        self.test_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onViewTest)
        ''' Up Button '''
        self.up_btn = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Up', pos=(100,10))
        self.up_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_press_up)
        self.up_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onViewTest)
        ''' Down Button '''
        self.down_btn = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Down', pos=(190,10))
        self.down_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_press_down)
        self.down_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onViewTest)

    def onViewTest(self, event):
        img = data[:,:,self.slice_num]
        print(img)
        self.image.changeImage(img)
        event.Skip()

    def on_press_up(self, event):
        self.slice_num += 1
        event.Skip()

    def on_press_down(self, event):
        self.slice_num -= 1
        event.Skip()

###############################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        v_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        colors = [("white", 1),
                  ("white", 1)]
        count = 1
        for color, subpanel in colors:
            panel = TopPanel(self, count, color, subpanel)
            hsizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
            count += 1

        bottom_panel = button_panel(self)
        v_sizer.Add(hsizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        v_sizer.Add(bottom_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(v_sizer)

###############################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Panels!", size=(600,500))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

###############################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
del app
```

Comment: I don't think `self.image` is, what you think it is, as it is declared as `SubPanel` rather than `SubPanel(parent)`

Comment: Thanks, in the end I found a work around by which i used multiple sub plots in the top panel rather than making separate panels